# Ngnix upstream timed out error

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, yii2, php-7

I have installed php7 and nginx on amazon ec2 instance and getting following error in yii2.

```
2016/11/11 07:00:33 [error] 11220#0: *14 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) 
while reading response header from upstream, client: XXX.XX.XXX.111, server: 
example.com, request: "POST /backend/web/index.php?r=site%2Flogin HTTP/1.1",
upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "example.com",
referrer: "http://example.com/backend/web/index.php?r=site%2Flogin"
```

Below are my nginx config file. (/etc/nginx/conf.d/virtual.conf)

```
server {
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;
    listen       80;
    server_name example.com;


    location / {
        root   /path/to/root;
        index index.php  index.html index.htm;
        # Redirect everything that isn't a real file to index.php
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    error_page  404              /errors/404.html;
    location = /errors/404.html {
        root   /path/to/root;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /errors/50x.html;
    location = /errors/50x.html {
        root   /path/to/root;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /path/to/root;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #fastcgi_pass   /var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }
    location ~ /\.(ht|svn|git) {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I already try to to do following but no luck :(

```
location / {
        ...
        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Check your code for errors, similar issue we resolve after fixing php code. Like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070299/nginx-php-fpm-504-timeout-error-upstream-timed-out-110-connection-timed-o

Answer (score 3):

Those odd errors are normal. For yii2, prefer unix socket (`/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock;` or whatever). In PHP-FPM config file (`php-fpm.conf`) set `request_terminate_timeout=30s`. In `php.ini` make `max_execution_time = 30`.

This is almost a fail proof configuration. Debug with `nginx -t` against each change and check frontend.

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
            root            /usr/share/nginx/html;
            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/html/$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            include         fastcgi_params;
    }
```

If still does not work, increase `client_max_body_size 128M;` to 1 GB.

Some distributions can be compiled keeping the PHP stuffs at `/etc/nginx/snippets/`. Run `cat` on `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params` to check what it has. If you add `/path/to/root/$fastcgi_script_name`, include `fastcgi_index`, make sure that it is `fastcgi_params;`.

Obviously religiously check `php-fpm.conf` for TCP or unix socket config.

Below stuff is not logically correct. 600s is huge time. But sometimes it works. Be careful with it on `nginx.conf` :

```
proxy_connect_timeout  600s;
proxy_send_timeout  600s;
proxy_read_timeout  600s;
fastcgi_send_timeout 600s;
fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
```

Comment: now getting another error. I already give 0777 permission to assets folder ugin root permission. Exception (Invalid Configuration) 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'The directory is not writable by the Web process: /usr/share/nginx/html/xxxx/backend/web/assets'

Comment: Disable SELinux. Run `$ chgrp <user> /usr/share/nginx/html/xxxx/backend/web/assets
$ chmod g+w /usr/share/nginx/html/xxxx/backend/web/assets`. `<user>` is `nginx` for CentOS, `www-data` for Ubuntu. Check `user` and `group` with `ps`

Answer (score 1):

Most likely an error with your upstream. Make sure  you can connect to and firewall is not blocking anything.

If you working with fastcgi (PHP-FPM), then you need to adjust fastcgi_read_timeout not proxy_read_timeout.

More info here: [Nginx upstream timed out (why and how to fix)](https://distinctplace.com/2017/04/22/nginx-upstream-timed-out/)

Answer (score 1):

First check `netstat -atpn | grep 9000`, Usually there are many connections that need to close like this:

```
tcp 1257 0 localhost:9000 localhost:46650 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp 1257 0 localhost:9000 localhost:46650 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp 1257 0 localhost:9000 localhost:46650 CLOSE_WAIT
```

Try enable `request_terminate_timeout` on `/etc/php/7.x/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` and give duration to terminate a request. Like this:

```
request_terminate_timeout=30s
```

And make sure enable `max_execution_time`  on `php.ini` like this:

```
max_execution_time = 30
```

Answer (score 0):

fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;

do you have anything listening on port 9000 ? try running 
netstat -atpn | grep 9000

Comment: now getting another error. I already give 0777 permission to assets folder ugin root permission. Exception (Invalid Configuration) 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'The directory is not writable by the Web process: /usr/share/nginx/html/xxxx/backend/web/assets'

Answer (score 0):

is your upstream app listening and available? i usually use something simple like 'telnet' to test the upstream is listening and responding:

```
[root@ip-10-0-1-1 opt]# telnet 127.0.0.1 8080
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]close

telnet> close
Connection closed.
[root@ip-10-0-1-1 opt]#
```

if your process isn't running (but open for access) you'll see a 'Connection Refused' error:

```
[root@ip-10-0-1-1 opt]# telnet localhost 8000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
```

HTH

Comment: now getting another error. I already give 0777 permission to assets folder ugin root permission. Exception (Invalid Configuration) 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'The directory is not writable by the Web process: /usr/share/nginx/html/xxxx/backend/web/assets'