# Nginx + Php-fpm fastcgi upstream timed out

Tags: php, nginx, timeout, fastcgi, fpm

I am having issues with a long-running PHP script:

```
<?php
sleep(70); # extend 60s
phpinfo();
```

Which gets terminated every time after 60 seconds with a response `504 Gateway Time-out` from Nginx.

When I inspect the Nginx errors I can see that the request times out:

```
... [error] 1312#1312: *2023 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, ... , upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock", ...
```

I went through the related questions and tried increasing the timeouts creating a `/etc/nginx/conf.d/timeout.conf` file with the following content:

```
proxy_connect_timeout 600;
proxy_send_timeout 600;
proxy_read_timeout 600;
send_timeout 600;
fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
fastcgi_send_timeout 600;
fastcgi_connect_timeout 600;
```

I also read through the Nginx documentation for both [fastcgi](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html) and [core](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html) modules, searching for any configurations with defaults set to 60 seconds.

I ruled out the `client_*` timeouts because they return `HTTP 408` instead of `HTTP 504` responses.

This is my Nginx server config portion of FastCGI:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

From what I read so far this doesn't seem to be an issue with PHP rather Nginx is to blame for the timeout. Nonetheless, I tried modifying the limits in PHP as well:

My values from the `phpinfo()`:

```
default_socket_timeout=600
max_execution_time=300
max_input_time=-1
memory_limit=512M
```

The php-fpm pool config also has the following enabled:

```
catch_workers_output = yes
request_terminate_timeout = 600
```

There is nothing in the php-fpm logs.

I am also using Amazon's Load Balancer to route to the server, but the timeout configuration is also increased from [the default 60 seconds](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/config-idle-timeout.html).

I don't know where else to look, during all the changes I restarted both php-fpm and nginx.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you have an error in your php code. We resolve similar issue like this answer by fixing our php code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070299/nginx-php-fpm-504-timeout-error-upstream-timed-out-110-connection-timed-o

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As it happens in these cases, I was actually editing a wrong configuration file that didn't get loaded by Nginx.

Adding the following to the right file did the trick:

```
fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
fastcgi_send_timeout 600;
fastcgi_connect_timeout 600;
```

Comment: In what file did you end up putting these changes?

Comment: I believe it was `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/your-site` which contained the configuration. Just make sure there are no overrides from the includes defined later on.

Comment: This worked for me. Ive putted this configuration inside /conf.d folder of Nginx installation. My environment is an AWS ElasticBeanstalk instance. There is a folder at /etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk. Inside this I created a new file with the new configuration