# Stuck at System screen when installing Moodle v3.8

Tags: moodle

I've installed Moodle v3.8 on Docker (php7.2-apache), but it's stucked at "System" screen when installing -error is attached
[Stuck screen photo here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1fHi.png)

Plz help me to solve this, thank a lot

Comment: This may be coming late and not very useful to you, but it might help someone else. You should allow the installation run for at least 10 minutes. If nothing BEGINS to shows up, then you can conclude it's frozen or stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when installing moodle 3.10 (PHP 7.2). Reloading the page got me further to plugin installation.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know it is stuck? It takes a while for the 'success' messages to start to appear - especially for the 'System'.
Same thing happened to me, I thought it was hanging, but it turns out I just had to leave it alone and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

These are few points you can take care of:

1. it'll take few minutes to get installed, until then don't refresh the page
2. if it doesn't show anything after few minutes delete files and folders of **moodledata** and restart moodle installation
3. open phpMyAdmin and refresh your database

Hope that'll help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with Moodle 4.0.1 so I understood the issue was version independent.

Nginx error log recorded a line of

`upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading upstream`

So I added to my **/etc/nginx/sites-available/default** config the following timeout related lines

```
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
...
  fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
  fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
  fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
}
```

as per this accepted answer [Nginx + Php-fpm fastcgi upstream timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59713432/nginx-php-fpm-fastcgi-upstream-timed-out#59724098)

I used 300 instead of 600 because the former is same as *max_execution_time* and *max_input_time* in my php.ini