# stuck at "Update to new version - Moodle 3.11.6+ (Build: 20220315)"

Tags: moodle

I've installed Moodle v3.11 on Ubuntu (php7.3-apache), but it's stucked at pressing button "Upgrade Moodle database now". So when it comes to this step it just freeze. Please help with that problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's my answer to similar question Moodle 3.8v](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67965836/8766282)

1. You can delete moodledata folder and set paths again, choose
   database name and database type.
2. Check with error and access logs(control panel of [LAMP](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-18-04) or [Laragon](https://laragon.org/) or [Bitnami](https://bitnami.com/stack/moodle/installer)).
3. Try in Private/Incognito window, sometimes that helps.

Thanks :)

Comment: thanks for you reply, I just re-install moodle and it did not freeze on second attempt