# phpmyadmin 504 timeout when logging in

Tags: php, mysql, nginx

I am setting up my server with nginx, faced with this annoying issue.
phpmyadmin is giving out 504 time out when logging in, even if I input wrong user credentials, it is showing 504 time out error.
my error log:

```
2021/10/29 09:46:48 [error] 154019#154019: *6670 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 122.178.182.104, server: localhost, request: "POST /phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock", host: "54.152.202.60"
```

Also, increasing the timeout value does not solve this error.

```
 location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

please help, thanks!

Comment: You say you've increased your timeout values, have you done so like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59724098/5897602

Comment: hi, thanks!
still I am not able to login, did that.

Comment: code now:
location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
  fastcgi_send_timeout 600;
  fastcgi_connect_timeout 600;
    }
but still not working. not able to login, connection timeout.

Comment: now , instead of 504 I am getting:
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out.
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.